# Auto click macro by using php

Tags: php

I'm using some macro recorder programs for auto clicking. These kinds of programs are made with Visual Basic, C++, etc., but I'd like to write one in PHP.

I'm loading a remote website by using PHP's cURL implementation. I'd like the PHP script to click exact mouse positions (for example: x:345px y:234px), wait for 15 seconds, then repeat.

Is this possible in PHP? If so, which php functions should I use?

Comment: Abusing some honest site, eh?

Comment: It could be a remote version of his own site for all we know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Selenium IDE](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) a Firefox extension to play and simple record test cases. It supports also to click on a specific coordinate.

Selenium command [ClickAt](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#clickAt)

Comment: perfect link. im checking commands right now. you ve been so helpfull for me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

PHP is a server-side language. It doesn't "click" - as it does not ever render the remote page, cURL just downloads it. If you're looking to automate such tasks, Selenium (an extension to Firefox) would probably be a better choice.

If you only need to simulate the requests that a browser is making (i.e. no JS interactions needed), you could watch them using Fiddler or Wireshark, then make the same requests using cURL. As long as the headers are the same, there is no simple way to distinguish them from requests made by an actual browser.

Comment: thanks for answer. ive never knew Selenium yet. im gonna test it right now. i hope it would work.

Comment: Fiddler or Wireshark methods are interesting. im gonna test them too. thanks. you ve been so helpfull for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you could do that, however it's merely impossible in practice.

In order to "simulate" the mouse clicks, you'd have parse and do at least an internal rendering of the page. This means parse (X)HTML, all the CSS and execute JavaScript. Sou you'd have to write a complete browser in PHP.